# NetworkStatsManager's queryDetailsForUid() method always returns old network usage for all the apps

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-trafficstats, networkstatsmanager

I have written a code to get network usage but                                            queryDetailsForUid(int networkType, String subscriberId,long startTime, long endTime, int uid) this method always returns old data.
How can I get updated data using `NetworkstatsManager` API?

```
    try {
            NetworkStats  networkStats = networkStatsManager.queryDetailsForUid(
                            ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI,
                            "",
                    0, System.currentTimeMillis()
                    ,
                    packageUid);

            NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
            networkStats.getNextBucket(bucket);
            Log.d("RX  "+packageUid," "+bucket.getRxBytes());
            Log.d("TX  "+packageUid," "+bucket.getTxBytes());

    } catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: i forgot to add that i have already visited all the questions related to NetworkStatsManager

Comment: Is there a reason you're only calling `getNextBucket()` once, instead of in a while loop checking `hasNextBucket()`?

Comment: Actually i haven't tried it with  'hasNextBucket()' , i will check for the same and let you know

Comment: Could you solve your problem? I get the old data which is more than two hours late!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the same method, It does not return old data.
You can test the date and time of your bucket using :

```
Log.d(TAG,"StartTime: "+bucket.getStartTimeStamp());
Log.d(TAG,"EndTime: "+bucket.getEndTimeStamp());
```

Check the end Timestamp , you shud see current date and time.
AFAIK, each bucket is of 2 hrs.

Whole Code:

```
            do {
            NetworkStats.Bucket bucket = new NetworkStats.Bucket();
            networkStatsByApp.getNextBucket(bucket);
            Log.d(TAG, "Bytes Recieved" + bucket.getRxBytes());
            Log.d(TAG, "Bytes Transfered" + bucket.getTxBytes());
            Log.d(TAG, "Bucket UID" + bucket.getUid());
            Log.d(TAG,"StartTime: "+bucket.getStartTimeStamp());
            Log.d(TAG,"EndTime: "+bucket.getEndTimeStamp());
            totalBuckets++;

        }while (networkStatsByApp.hasNextBucket());
```

Comment: Any idea how to use it on Android Q? Sadly it doesn't allow to get the subscriberId anymore... Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56611173/878126